# Not able to map name query result to POJO class

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
I am implementing microservices using spring jpa. 

Follwing is my repository interface: 

public interface FormsRepository {
    public List findCustomer(Integer Id);
}

Impl class for above :

@Repository
public class FormsRepositoryServiceImpl implements FormsRepository { 
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
    public List findCustomerFieldDetails(Integer persId) {
         Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findCustomer", CustomerDetails.class);
         query.setParameter(1, persId);
         List custDetail =query.getResultList();
        return custDetail;
    }
}

The Named native query is present in orm.xml and the CustomerDetails.class is a normal POJO class and not an entity class. We are not creating entity classes. We are creating consolidated POJOs.

I am not able to map the results to the POJO fields.

Suppose the query is : select a.id ,b.name from a,b and both id and name are present in the POJO class how do we map it?

Getting below error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Also, if we do not use result class in createNamedQuery method, the data returned is a type Object and while iterating through that as well we are getting ClassCastException:

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.accenture.apsp.document.service.domain.CustomerDetails

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation for this purpose like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "findCustomer",
    query =
        "select a.id ,b.name from a,b",
    resultSetMapping = "findCustomer_dto"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "findCustomer_dto",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = CustomerDetails.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class)
        }
    )
)
```